# Передача состояние useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как мне вынести состояние **useState** из файла. Нужно экспортировать именно **sliderCount** для дальнейшей работы. Заранее спасибо.

Есть 2 файла. В первом файле создается функция с **useState** и при клике на кнопки изменяет его состояние. Во втором файле я хочу получать измененное состояние **useState** из первого файла и дальше работать с ним.

Делать условия и т.д, как например:

```
if(sliderCount == 1){
    console.log('Number 1')
}

if(sliderCount == 2){
    console.log('Number 2')
}
```

Первый файл:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

function ContainerAtwSwap() {
    const [sliderCount, setSliderCount] = useState(0)
    return (
        <div className="container_button__swap-main">
            <div className="dropdown">
                <div className="dropdown-content">
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(1)}>№1</button>
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(2)}> №2</button>
                    <button className="button__swap-button" onClick={() => setSliderCount(3)}>№3</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ContainerAtwSwap
```

Второй файл:

```
import React from 'react';

function WorkingEnvironment() {
    ..Вот тут хотелось делать условия и т.д
    return (
        <div className='boxControl scroll' id='boxSliderOne'>
            <div className='container-slider'>
                {}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default WorkingEnvironment;
```

Comment: У вас компонент первого файла является родителем второго?

Comment: Нет, просто два файла

Comment: В таком случае можете предоставить примерное дерево ваших элементов, чтобы было понятно, как эти ваши два компонента располагаются относительно друг друга?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй эти два компонента обернуть в один общий компонент. И в этом компоненте создай state свой и передавай им в виде пропсов